# nginx enable fastcgi_cache dynamically?

Tags: nginx

I try to find smart way of enabling fasctcgi_cache on demand
the default way of it is enable by default unless you do

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass true;
fastcgi_no_cache  true;
```

and I try to achieve the opposite.

what I have right now is:

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $upstream_http_no_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache  $upstream_http_no_cache;
```

I send in all my urls the header `no_cache: 1;`

in the urls that I need the cache I send the header `no_cache: 0;`
 so the cache is not disabled.

Its working but I am not loving it.
and I cant use "if" in the config because of the "[If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)" thing

is there some way of making it off by default and trigger it on when needed?

Comment: Why don't you just use normal proper Cache-Control: headers. Then you don't have to worry about anything.

Comment: its not the same thing, or I am missing something? nginx give me server side caching

Comment: Why you "not loving it"?

Comment: feels too hacky because if somehow the dont cache header dont get sent than the url is getting cached accidentally

Answer (score 0):

So you wan't to don't cache by default and have some header to cache. You could do it with `map` directive:

```
map $upstream_http_no_cache $no_cache {
    default $upstream_http_no_cache;
    "" "1";
}

...

fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache  $no_cache;
```

Variable `$no_cache` defaults to `$upstream_http_no_cache` (that is NO-CACHE header from uptream), but empty value (i.e. no header set) maps to `1`.

Comment: thanks seems likes a good approach but some why the map directive not working correctly I am using nginx 1.8.1 and the $no_cache is always ending up equal to 1